# Python method of child with less input, best practice

Tags: python, parent-child, signature, python-class

I have two classes, `A` and and it's child `B`. The `__init__` of `A` uses `same_method(*some_input)`.
In `B` this method should be adjusted to take no input. (This is a simplified example).

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, *some_input) -> None:
        self.same_method(*some_input)

    def same_method(self, *some_input):
        print(*some_input)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def same_method(self):
        print('This is B')
```

Expected output:

```
This is A
This is B
```

This example works fine. If the method is renamed to `__same_method` however the output is:

```
This is A
```

It seems that it runs `A.__same_method` in `B.__init__`.

As my main project contains many Dunder methods and I only recently introduced inheritance I was wondering if there is a way to make this work with Dunder methods as well. Or is this something I really should not do?
Whats the best practice for child methods with a different signature?

(I'm using Python 3.9 with PyCharm 2021.2.3)